# What is shown outside of the elevator at the end of Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

At the end of Portal 2 you take an elevator ride and a bunch of small rooms flash past with turrets and other things in them. I've been through it a few times but I still couldn't make out what was in some of them. Any pictures I've seen have been too blurry or low-quality.  What's in these rooms?

Comment: I rewrote this to be a real question instead of a screenshot request.  The accepted answer is still perfect IMO.  [Relevant Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/seriously-a-screenshot-service).

Comment: @MatthewRead Excellent. This should clear up any confusion over the intent of this question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here are the screenshots of the rooms you see on the elevator ride up to the surface at the end of Portal 2. Apologies beforehand as some of the screenshots are a little fuzzy, but the descriptions should help clarify any details that may be unclear.

[image: A row of four turrets initially targeting the player who then go on to sing]

A row of four turrets initially targeting the player who then go on to sing

[image: Two turrets singing]

Two turrets singing

[image: Four partially assembled/defective turrets]

Four partially assembled/defective turrets

[image: Three turrets at 90 degree angles]

Three turrets at 90 degree angles (apparently mis-assembled)

[image: Four turrets staring at the Aperture Science Weighted Storage Cube]

Four turrets staring at the Aperture Science Weighted Storage Cube

[image: Four turrets surrounding another cube staring at the player]

Four turrets surrounding another cube staring at the player

[image: Eight turrets facing the player in two rows of four]

Eight turrets facing the player in two rows of four

[image: Two turrets who appear to be behind a ruptured transportation tunnel (would explain the angle of the turret to the left) or possibly tangled in roots (see comments)]

Two turrets who appear to be behind a ruptured transportation tunnel (would explain the angle of the turret to the left) or possibly tangled in roots (see comments)

[image: A large room filled with an assembly of turrets, in the spotlight is the 'tenor' turret and in the background is the oversized 'animal king' turret]

A large room filled with an assembly of turrets, in the spotlight is the 'tenor' turret and in the background is the oversized 'animal king' turret

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand that getting clear pictures can be a problem since they flash by so fast but these are the clearest pictures I've seen so far. :)

Comment: bnb, I'm happy to here that thank you very much it was a pleasure to answer your question since I am a big Portal fan myself and it has turned out to be one of my best answers so thank you.

Comment: On the second to last picture it looks more to me like the turrets have become entangled in some potato roots. What do you think?

Comment: Interesting hypothesis, the primary reason for me suggesting that it was a transportation tube was the splintered steel beams as well as the intense motion observed when watching the video however the potato roots is a highly likely possibility as it would be accustomed to Valve's sense of humour in easter eggs and hidden details.

Comment: The turrets at 90-degree angles are defective too, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

Viewing this in 720p should help you see what's going on: